# How to enable show on lock screen permission in Redmi 5 programatically

Tags: lockscreen, redmi-device

[image]

I want to open activity through push notification, but in mi devices it is not opening due to "Show on lock screen" permission of, how to enable this programmatically.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem.StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i have used below code for wake lock, working in all devices except xiamoi device  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

Comment: With this code not working i have already tried this

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Any updates on this ?